# Sms receiver without Activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am working on an sms receiver app but i do not need any activity.If i use an activity there is no problem and program works fine but when i remove main_activity from manifest and delete main_activity.xml and main_activity.java, app cannot take sms which received.Here is my code.Where am i wrong?

----Manifest----

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androidexample.broadcastreceiver"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


        <receiver android:name="com.androidexample.broadcastreceiver.IncomingSms">   
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"  />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>

</manifest>
```

----IncomingSms.java---

```
package com.androidexample.broadcastreceiver;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Get the object of SmsManager
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        System.out.println("----------------------->>>>> GELDİ");
        // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {

            if (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                    Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);

                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                    toast.show();

                } // end for loop
              } // bundle is null

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the past few years, the user must manually launch one of your activities (or something else must launch one of your components with an explicit `Intent`) before any manifest-registered broadcast receivers will work. See "Launch controls on stopped applications" from [the Android 3.1 release notes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html).

Comment: @BahadırYılmaz: You are welcome to read this blog post: http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html Regardless, you will need to leave your activity there, so that the user can run it, so that you can receive SMS messages after that point. The user will want this activity anyway: to control the behavior of your app, to read your license agreement, to read the documentation, to learn where to turn for technical support, etc.